# client communicate directly with Oracle database on server OK to to do, or pose security risk or other issue?

Tags: database, oracle

Newbie question. I'm developing a web application (I'm using Flex/AS3, but for the purposes of this question I suppose it could be any language) and can write SQL commands directly in it to access data (to and from) Oracle database. The advantage of this is eliminating the middle tier (e.g. Java, PHP, Ruby, etc.). Are there any disadvantages?

If I were to use a middle tier language, it would be simply to pass the SQL command from client to Oracle, so I'm not sure what benefit it brings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middle tear usually brings a significant ease of use, which lowers development time, and flexibility over use of services outside of your Flash app.

What are you doing to access the services directly?  Are you using the socket classes, or something else?

Comment: I hear it's possible to do this within Flex/AS3, although at this moment I haven't developed any code to do it yet. My belief was this was a security risk somehow, but then I thought to research it a bit more. Thus this post. At the heart of it I suppose we could replace "Flex/AS3" with any client side language able to send SQL commands. If the middle tier isn't needed other than as a pass-through of these commands, can it safely be dropped? The thinking being... those SQL commands are visible at the client anyway, why bother handing them to a middle tier just to regenerate them again?

Comment: Your question made me believe you already had code working to access the database directly.  I've heard of people talking directly to the database using sokcets, but it was limited and experimental.  It's not practical.  I've never seen a case where you would generate SQL commands in the client and pass them to a middleware.  I'm not sure what security issue you think is introduced or you are avoiding.

Comment: Are you saying from your experience (I'm sure you know more than I do), one cannot issue, or it is impractical to issue, SQL commands from Flex/AS3? Note that in my thinking the SQL commands are predetermined (that is, hardcoded) into Flex/AS3 code (that is, there's no "generation" of new SQL commands/strings based on user input, etc).  Regarding security issues, perhaps it's common practice (?) to look at the SQL strings in the middle tier to check for SQL Injection (etc.) or transmit user id/pwd with client commands to validate client commands in middle tier before sending on to server, etc.

Comment: I'm saying it is impractical to issue SQL Commands direct from ActionSCript. You'll have to write your own ActionScript SQL drivers to do so.  There is a project out there that did this; but I believe it ran into limitations and was left incomplete. In my work; SQL Commands are rarely generated w/o taking into account input from users.